Can I run a Bitcoin Core 27 wallet on two devices at the same time?
I have two machines (desktop and laptop) and I use the laptop as a backup device.
Can I use the same wallet on both of them at the same time?

Did you mean that you use the same wallet on both, or that you just run two nodes in parallel?

Same wallet on both.

No, running multiple instances of Bitcoin Core using the same wallet is not recommended, see e.g. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/123276/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3499/5406

I edited your question to incorporate the clarification that you are asking about using the same wallet on two devices. Please edit your question if I didn’t properly capture the intent of your question.

Running multiple instances of Bitcoin Core using the same wallet is not recommended.
Concerns include (this is not an exhaustive list):

If you use a non-HD wallet, eventually each instance of the wallet will start generating different new keys and they will no longer work as a backup of each other nor recognize all funds belonging to the wallet
If you use an HD wallet and both instances send transactions, they may produce conflicting transactions at the same time. As they each add their transaction to the own wallet, neither wallet will notice the other transaction until it is confirmed. Presumably, if only one wallet creates a transaction the other instance would recognize it as pertaining to its own wallet and start tracking it, and once one of a set of conflicting transactions is confirmed any conflict would be resolved.
If both wallets are used to give out addresses, you may end up giving out the same address for multiple invoices
If only one wallet gives out addresses, the other wallet may not notice transactions because it hasn’t started tracking addresses that it didn’t give out. The second node may need to be resynchronized to pick up on the overlooked transactions.
Transactions from the two wallets may send change to the same change address when they create transactions
Metadata such as transaction labels, and notes about recipients would not be synchronized
There would probably be additional unexpected issues caused by the diverging synchronization state

Also see:

Is it Safe to Share a Wallet File Between Multiple Bitcoin Core Instances Using the New Wallet DB Technology?
What happens when the same wallet (private key) is used on several
machines?


What if I dont run them at the same time? Would that make any difference? Also, what if I copied my bitcoin folder to the laptop after syncing the blockchain?
